# Does Fabric Support Command Substitution?

Tags: python, sed, fabric

I'm new to fabric and rough around the edges with python. 
I'm trying my hand at writing a small script that updates a file with the ID of a public gpg keyring.

In pseudo-code:

```
    sed("./conf", 'GPG_KEY='085C042B'', 'GPG_KEY='`commandoutput`', use_sudo=true,backup='')
```

Where `commandoutput` is the output of the following command:

```
    bash$ gpg --list-keys | grep pub | grep 4096R | awk '{ print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f2
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to accomplish this.
Can I pipe or capture the output of a fabric run command?

**Update #1:**
BMW offered helpful suggestions below, however I'm not quite sure how to integrate into fabric. Here's what I have now:

```
DUPLY_DIR = "/etc/duply/fullbackup/"
    with cd(DUPLY_DIR):
        GPG_KEY1="085C042B"
        GPG_KEY2="$(gpg --list-keys | awk '/pub/&&/4096R/{split($2,a,"/"); print a[2]}')"
sed("./conf", 'GPG_KEY1', 'GPG_KEY2', use_sudo=true, backup='')
```

But this produces an error:

```
File "/home/fabric/fabfile.py", line 44, in stage_gpg
    GPG_KEY2="$(gpg --list-keys | awk '/pub/&&/4096R/{split($2,a,"/"); print a[2]}')" TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, the gpg command can be replaced by

```
gpg --list-keys |awk '/pub/&&/4096R/{split($2,a,"/");print a[2]}'
```

replace GPG key "085C042B" by gpg ouptut on all *.conf files.

```
GPG_KEY1="085C042B"
GPG_KEY2=$(gpg --list-keys |awk '/pub/&&/4096R/{split($2,a,"/");print a[2]}' )
sed -i "s/$GPG_KEY1/$GPG_KEY2/" *.conf
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this out but I don't think I'm integrating into fabric's syntax correctly. The update to the question is my current code, but I'm still experimenting. Any further suggestions appreciated. Thanks!